# Machine learning with my car dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model

I’m very new to machine learning.
I have a dataset with data given me by a f1 race. User is playing this game and is giving me this dataset.
With machine learning, I have to work with this data and when a user (I know they are 10) plays a game I have to recognize who’s playing.

The data consists of datagram packet occurred in 1/10 second freq, the packets contains the following `Time, laptime, lapdistance, totaldistance, speed, car position, traction control, last lap time, fuel, gear,..`

I’ve thought to use a kmeans used in a supervised way.
Which algorithm could be better?

Comment: there isn't any definitive answer, and you will have to try a numerous classification algorithms to see what works best, maybe you can describe your data a bit... it might help to direct you in the right direction

Comment: Every 1/10 second user gives me a datagram packet that contains:

Comment: Time, laptime, lapdistance, totaldistance, speed, car position, traction control, last lap time, fuel, gear,..

Comment: @gio no need to repeat in the comments what you have already included in your post...

Comment: @desertnaut I edit his post to reflect the comments, which added new data... you can downgrade my answer like someone else did, at least you will have a reason

Comment: Didn't downvote your question (it's my principle to avoid downvoting questions from new users), but I did vote for it to be closed as too broad...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is somewhat a broad question, so I'll try my best

kmeans is unsupervised algorithm meaning it will find the classes itself and it best used when you know there are multiple classes but you don't know what exactly they are... using it with labeled data just means you will compute the distance of new vector v to each vector in the dataset and pick the one (or ones using majority vote) which give the min distance , this is not considered as machine learning

in this case when you do have the labels, supervised approach will yield much better results

I suggest try [random forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html) at first, those are the most basic and common algorithms and they give pretty good results

if you haven't achieve the desired accuracy you can use deep learning and build a neural network with input layer as big as your packet's values and output layer of the number of classes, in between you can use one or multiple hidden layers with various nodes, but this is advanced approach and you better pick up some experience in machine learning field before pursue it

Note: the data is a time series, meaning that every driver has it's own behaviour of driving a car, so data should be considered as bulks of points, with this you can apply pattern matching technics, also there are a several neural networks build exactly for this data (like [RNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network)) but this is far far advanced and much more difficult to implement

Comment: thanks you very much!
..And what do you thing about svm?

Comment: yeah, you should try it too, it has a problem and need the data to be linearly separable otherwise need to use a kernel function to cast the data to a higher dim, but it's a good start too

Answer (score 0):

The task must be a multiclass classification. The very first step in any machine learning activity is to define a score metric (https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use/). That allows you to compare models between themselves and decide which is better. Then build a base model with random forest or/and logistic regression as suggested in another answer - they perform well out-of-the-box. Then try to play with features and understand which of them are more informative. And don't forget about a visualizations - they give many hints for data wrangling, etc.